# Cómo mostrar ubicación actual MapKit Swift 2

Tags: ios, xcode

Hola estoy implementando en mi proyecto de Xcode con swift 2 MapKit en el cual muestro un mapa con varios marcadores pero además necesito mostrar la ubicación actual del usuario, busque en varias páginas pero sin lograrlo.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class mapController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var myMapView: MKMapView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapTajMahal()

    }

    func mapTajMahal()
    {
        //Taj Mahal Coordinates: 27.175015, 78.042139

        // Coordinates
        let tajLat:CLLocationDegrees = -39.849254
        let tajLong:CLLocationDegrees = -71.994215

        let tajCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: tajLat, longitude: tajLong)

        let mocho = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -39.849152, longitude: -71.943082)
        let aitue = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -39.849581, longitude: -71.945078)
        let rucapillan = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -39.833403841808995, longitude:-72.07239013854979)
        let c_elportal = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -39.848834,longitude: -71.937480)
        let c_los_alamos = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -39.851652, longitude: -71.931052)
        let c_lago_neltume = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -39.77999, longitude: -71.95708)
        let c_peumayen = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -39.848467, longitude: -71.938013)
        let domos = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -39.850835, longitude: -71.940623)
        let patagonia = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -39.858635, longitude: -71.918520)
        let madero = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -39.858635, longitude: -71.918520
        )

        //Span
        let latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.2
        let longDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.2
        let tajSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: latDelta, longitudeDelta: longDelta)

        let tajRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: tajCoordinate, span: tajSpan)

        myMapView.setRegion(tajRegion, animated: true )

        let tajAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        tajAnnotation.title = "Neltume"
        tajAnnotation.subtitle = "She walks in beauty"
        tajAnnotation.coordinate = tajCoordinate


        let mochoannotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        mochoannotation.title = "Mocho Neltume"
        mochoannotation.coordinate = mocho

        let aitueanotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        aitueanotation.title = "Aitue Expediciones"
        aitueanotation.coordinate = aitue

        let rucapillananotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        rucapillananotation.title = "Rafting Excursiones Restaurant Hostal Cabañas Rucapillan"
        rucapillananotation.coordinate = rucapillan

        let c_elportalanotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        c_elportalanotation.title = "Cabañas el Portal"
        c_elportalanotation.coordinate = c_elportal

        let c_los_alamosanotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        c_los_alamosanotation.title = "Cabañas los Alamos"
        c_los_alamosanotation.coordinate = c_los_alamos

        let c_lago_neltumeanotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        c_lago_neltumeanotation.title = "Cabañas Lago Neltume"
        c_lago_neltumeanotation.coordinate = c_lago_neltume

        let c_peumayenatonation = MKPointAnnotation()
        c_peumayenatonation.title = "Cabañas Peumayen"
        c_peumayenatonation.coordinate = c_peumayen

        let domosanotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        domosanotation.title = "Cabañas Karü Domos del Fuy"
        domosanotation.coordinate = domos

        let patagoniaanotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        patagoniaanotation.title = "Cabañas Patagonia Mawida"
        patagoniaanotation.coordinate = patagonia

        let maderoanotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        maderoanotation.title = "Restaurante Refugio del Madero"
        maderoanotation.coordinate = madero

        myMapView.addAnnotation(mochoannotation)
        myMapView.addAnnotation(aitueanotation)
        myMapView.addAnnotation(rucapillananotation)
        myMapView.addAnnotation(c_elportalanotation)
        myMapView.addAnnotation(c_los_alamosanotation)
        myMapView.addAnnotation(c_lago_neltumeanotation)
        myMapView.addAnnotation(c_peumayenatonation)
        myMapView.addAnnotation(patagoniaanotation)
        myMapView.addAnnotation(maderoanotation)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo que hay que agregar es NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription en Info.plist. y en el Controller del mapa.

```
        myMapView.showsUserLocation = true


        myMapView.userLocationVisible; true


        self.locatinManager.delegate = self

        self.locatinManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

        self.locatinManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        self.locatinManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        self.myMapView.showsUserLocation = true


    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {


        let location = locations.last

        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)

        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 2.2, longitudeDelta: 2.2))

        self.mapa2.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        self.locatinManager.stopUpdatingLocation()


        let mocho = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -39.848123, longitude: -71.940584)

        let mochoannotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        mochoannotation.title = "Neltume"
        mochoannotation.coordinate = mocho

         mapa2.addAnnotation(mochoannotation)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Los mapas (clase `MKMapKit`) tienen una propiedad `showsUserLocation`.

Alcanzaría con hacer

```
myMapView.showsUserLocation = true
```

Puedes ver la [documentación](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/showsUserLocation) (en inglés), también hay otras propiedades que te pueden interesar como ser `userLocation` o `userTrackingMode`.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta, por lo que vi el _userlocation_ es para detectar la posición y _locationvisible_ es para verla marcada en el mapa pero no lo logre hacerlo funcionar.